# Parsing time in minutes from String like "6m 5d3h "

Tags: java

I wish to turn a String looking like this:

```
String string = "5d3h6m";
```

Or even like this:

```
String string = " 44h 22d";
```

In any order, and with any number of spaces into an **int** symbolising the time in minutes.

(D=days H=Hours M=Minutes)

The problems I have had:

1. Finding the characters in any order
2. Getting any number of digits that appear before the letter

The following code is me trying to find a solution to the two problems (I am aware it is terrible code, that is why I am here, and no, I do not wish to be spoonfed):

```
if(timestring.contains(":")){
                            String[] timestringarray = timestring.split(":");
                            int timeinminutes = 0;
                            int timestringarraylength = timestringarray.length;
                            while(timestringarraylength>0){ 
                                if(timestringarray[timestringarraylength].matches("d{1}|D{1}")){
                                    timestring.replace("d{1}|D{1}","");
                                    long days = TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(Integer.valueOf(timestring), TimeUnit.DAYS);
                                    int daysint = (int) (long) days;
                                    timeinminutes+=daysint;
                                }
                                if(timestringarray[timestringarraylength].matches("h{1}|H{1}")){
                                    timestring.replace("h{1}|H{1}","");
                                    long hours = TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(Integer.valueOf(timestring), TimeUnit.HOURS);
                                    int hoursint = (int) (long) hours;
                                    timeinminutes+=hoursint;
                                }
                                if(timestringarray[timestringarraylength].matches("m{1}|M{1}")){
                                    timestring.replace("m{1}|M{1}","");
                                    long mins = TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(Integer.valueOf(timestring), TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                                    int minsint = (int) (long) mins;
                                    timeinminutes+=minsint;
                                }
                                timestringarraylength--;
                            }
                            signConfig.set("Sign.time", Integer.valueOf(timeinminutes));
                        }
```

To specify, the String is a time entered by the user and won't change during the processing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, define `it doesn't even work...` and try to concentrate on one practical question. Questions like `how to implement this?` are rarely welcomed on stackoverflow

Comment: Also, this question might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403851/parsing-time-strings-like-1h-30min?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This should get you started

Given that *it doesn't work* isn't very helpful, this is about all you can hope for. Some direction on how to convert arbitrary encoded duration intervals into something you can process further.

This requires JDK 1.7+ because of the `switch` on `String`. Otherwise you will have to convert that to an `if/elseif/else` block.

[Regular Expression `(\d+)([hmsd])` explained](http://regex101.com/r/cB9kL9/1).

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Q24917480
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)([hmsd])");
        final Matcher m = p.matcher("5d3h6m");
        long totalMillis = 0;
        while (m.find())
        {
            final int duration = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
            final TimeUnit interval = toTimeUnit(m.group(2));
            final long l = interval.toMillis(duration);
            totalMillis = totalMillis + l;
            System.out.format("TimeUnit.%s.toMillis(%s) = %d\n", interval.name(), duration, l);
        }
        System.out.println("TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(totalMillis) = " + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(totalMillis));
        System.out.println("TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(totalMillis) = " + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(totalMillis));
        System.out.println("TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(totalMillis) = " + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(totalMillis));
    }

    public static TimeUnit toTimeUnit(@Nonnull final String c)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case "s": return TimeUnit.SECONDS;
            case "m": return TimeUnit.MINUTES;
            case "h": return TimeUnit.HOURS;
            case "d": return TimeUnit.DAYS;
            default: throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("%s is not a valid code [smhd]", c));
        }
    }
}
```

#### The expected output is:

```
TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(5) = 432000000
TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(3) = 10800000
TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(6) = 360000
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(totalMillis) = 443160
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(totalMillis) = 7386
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(totalMillis) = 5
```

Comment: Great thanks for your help. I haven't thoroughly tested through using you method but I'm sure I will be able to extrapolate what I need from your example and customise for myself.

Comment: Also, I never meant to not be specific at all by saying "it doesn't work", I more like meant "I have tried for a very long time and can't get this to work, I probably don't know enough java to do this, could anybody help?"