# Java JodaTime: "123" should be (long) 123. How can I do that without having "ms" for example at the end: "10ms"?

Tags: java, jodatime, periodformatter

How do I format the PeriodFormatter from Java-JodaTime to handle Strings like:
"10s" = (long) 10000; <-- I solved that.
"10ms" = (long) 10. 
"10" = long 10.  <-- Only here is my problem!

I can handle the first two commands with Joda Time with this link:
[Parsing time strings like "1h 30min"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403851/parsing-time-strings-like-1h-30min)

But my problem: How can I convert the "10" to millisec. without an empty appending?

```
    PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
       .appendSeconds().appendSuffix("s")
       .appendMillis().appendSuffix("ms")
       .append###########().appendSuffix("")  // <--here is my problem. Keep it empty won't work: InvalidFormatException
       .toFormatter();
    Period p = formatter.parsePeriod("10s"); // <-- this works
    p = formatter.parsePeriod("10");   // <-- Here is my problem. It should be 10 millisec.
    System.out.println("Time in millisec.: "+p.getMillis());
```

I could not find anything in the doc or at Google. So thanks for your help.

As a **workaround** I am using a regular expression above of the Joda-Code to catch strings with only digits inside:

```
    if (time.matches("[0-9]+")) {
        return Long.parseLong(time);
    }     
    PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder() 
        .appendWeeks().appendSuffix("w")                     
        .appendDays().appendSuffix("d")
        .appendHours().appendSuffix("h")
        .appendMinutes().appendSuffix("m")
        .appendSeconds().appendSuffix("s")            
        .appendMillis().appendSuffix("ms")            
        .toFormatter();     
    return p.toStandardDuration().getMillis();
```

Comment: Try this: `.appendMillis().appendSuffix("ms", "")`

Comment: Good idea, but it's causing an error: "invalid format". The error comes at "formatter.parsePeriod("10");"

Comment: Can you try to remove the `.appendSuffix("ms")` ?

Comment: No, because I need both: "10ms" and "10" as milliseconds   :-(

Comment: So it's done. I am using a regular expression above the Joda Code, see above. But if you got a Joda solution, I would be happier, cause it's cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

If the input does not contain a literal then simply leave it out from your builder-pattern. So parsing only a number to milliseconds can be solved with following simple code:

```
   PeriodFormatter pf = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
       .appendMillis()
       .toFormatter();
   Period p = pf.parsePeriod("10");
   System.out.println("Time in millisec.: " + p);
   // Time in millisec.: PT0.010S
   System.out.println("Time in millisec.: " + p.getMillis());
   // Time in millisec.: 10
```

Comment: Even, a good idea. But I it works only for "10" or "10ms". But I need both: 
.appendSeconds().appendSuffix("s")
.appendMillis()
.appendMillis().appendSuffix("ms"). With this code I got an error with: "invalid format ''10ms" is malformed at "ms".

Comment: @AlexHH Then you should define TWO different patterns in two period formatters and try each one for parsing your input. Maybe even 3 different patterns?!

Comment: Oh, then it's cleaner to use a regular expression above my Joda Code. I inserted it in my question above. Thanks for your help! I am sorry that I didn't get that workaround before I asked my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution without regexp:

```
PeriodFormatter f = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
            .appendSeconds().appendSuffix("s")
            .appendMillis().appendSuffix("ms")
            .appendMillis()
            .toFormatter();
```

To be honest, this a bit of an hack and will also parse a string like `"1s10ms10"` which is awkward, BUT this an edge case that you should not encounter and, more importantly, will achieve what you want. The following strings will be correctly evaluated: `"1s10ms"`, `"1s"`, `"10ms"`, `"10"`

Comment: Thanks, lazel.
It throws me an IllegalArgumentException: InvalidFormat "12345ms" is malformed at "s". So, he knows the "m" for minute, but not the "ms". It only works, if I delete the ".appendMillis().appendSuffix("ms")" row. But then he don't know the "ms".

Comment: Uhm... That's tricky. On a first analysis, I guess the problem is that `m` are confused with `ms`. I suppose that the last element is treated specially, something like: if all the string has been read, then give priority to the last element... Well, if something come up in mind, I'll tell you