# How to parse duration in format "HHmm" using JodaTime?

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm trying to shift datetime by a Duration which I get in the format "HHmm", for example "0010" meaning 10 minutes.

I've found similar ticket ([Parsing time strings like "1h 30min"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403851/parsing-time-strings-like-1h-30min)) but I can't make it work properly.

Here's the code:

```
PeriodFormatter hoursMinutes = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendHours().appendMinutes().toFormatter();
Duration duration = hoursMinutes.parsePeriod("0010").toStandardDuration();
duration.getStandardMinutes(); //Returns 600
```

For some reason, I get 600 minutes instead of 10. So it looks like the minutes were interpreted as hours, but I can't understand why. I've tried adding `.maximumParsedDigits(2)` for hours, but the result was the same.

Why is my code wrong? Is there some other way to initialize duration parser? Something, where I could just use the standard format like "HHmm"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue was really with the maximum parseddigits. I only had to add it before hours, not minutes. So the solution is this:

```
PeriodFormatter hoursMinutes =
                new PeriodFormatterBuilder().maximumParsedDigits(2).appendHours().appendMinutes().toFormatter();
Duration duration = hoursMinutes.parsePeriod("0010").toStandardDuration();
duration.getStandardMinutes(); //Returns 10
```

Comment: Ah okay, you were quicker +1 so I deleted my answer. Personally I prefer a pattern-based approach., for example using my lib Time4J: `Duration<ClockUnit> d = Duration.formatter(ClockUnit.class, "#hmm").parse("0010");
long minutes = ClockUnit.MINUTES.convert(d);
System.out.println(minutes); // 10`

Comment: I also like your solution more, but I don't want to add another library just for this.

Comment: too bad that they did not include this in jsr-310

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html#getStandardMinutes()):

> getStandardMinutes
>
> public long getStandardMinutes()
>
> Gets the length of this duration in minutes assuming that there are the standard number of milliseconds in a minute. This method assumes that there are 60 seconds in a minute and 1000 milliseconds in a second. All currently supplied chronologies use this definition.
>
> This returns getMillis() / 60000. The result is an integer division,
>   thus excess milliseconds are truncated.
>
> **Returns**: the length of the duration in standard seconds

Seeing as 600 is actually 10 minutes in seconds (`60 * 10`), you got the answer you expected.

Comment: I don't think the documentation says what you are implying. The problem is not in the `getStandardMinutes()`, but in the Duration value. When I call `getStandardHours()`, it prints `10`. When I add this duration to the ReadableInstant like DateTime, it is really shifted by 10 hours, not 10 minutes.

Comment: So yes... documentation says what you are implying, but it's lying. `getMillis() / 60000` obviously isn't a value in seconds.