# JAVA Hours to duration

Tags: java, time, duration

I have an app where i need to check if travel is in duration between 4 hours and 30 hours, I store it as a strings *"04:00"* and *"30:00"*, then i try to parse it using `LocalTime.parse()`, *"04:00"* is parsed successfully but *"30:00"* gets an error for invalid format, what could be best way to parse duration hours from a string ?

Comment: What does `"30:00"` mean?  Is that just absolute duration?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403851/parsing-time-strings-like-1h-30min does this help?

Comment: ... Seems trivial; split on the ":" and compare numbers.

Comment: Show us your code. How are you storing / parsing these strings?

Comment: Are you looking for the Period class?

Comment: Or using a duration formatter in my lib Time4J: `java.time.Duration td = TemporalType.THREETEN_DURATION.from(net.time4j.Duration.formatter(ClockUnit.class, "hh:mm").parse("30:00"));`

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you're storing it somehow wrong. I suggest to store it in way [`Duration.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) can handle it, in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format.

```
Examples:

    "PT20.345S" -- parses as "20.345 seconds"
    "PT15M"     -- parses as "15 minutes" (where a minute is 60 seconds)
    "PT10H"     -- parses as "10 hours" (where an hour is 3600 seconds)
    "P2D"       -- parses as "2 days" (where a day is 24 hours or 86400 seconds)
    "P2DT3H4M"  -- parses as "2 days, 3 hours and 4 minutes"
    "P-6H3M"    -- parses as "-6 hours and +3 minutes"
    "-P6H3M"    -- parses as "-6 hours and -3 minutes"
    "-P-6H+3M"  -- parses as "+6 hours and -3 minutes"
```

So then you can just do:

```
Duration dur30H = Duration.parse("PT30H"); // 30h
Duration dur4H = Duration.parse("PT4H"); // 4h
Duration travelTime = Duration.parse("P1D"); // 1D
boolean result = travelTime.compareTo(dur30H) <= 0 && travelTime.compareTo(dur4H) >= 0; // true
```