# Converting 2 strings with milliseconds into date and calculating time difference java

Tags: java, date, type-conversion, milliseconds, datetime-conversion

I have 2 strings with minutes, seconds and miliseconds

```
String startTime = "02:58.917"
String finishTime = "04:03.332"
```

and I need to calculate time difference. As i understand (but I'm not sure) the most simple way is to convert them into Date type, but I don't know how to do it correctly, escpecially with milliseconds. 
P.S. If anybode know how I can calculate time difference without converting to Date, it also fits.
Help pls!

UPD: I need to get result in the same format, like this "01:04:415"

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403851/parsing-time-strings-like-1h-30min

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: @AliAhmad, it is useful, but I need to get result in the same format, like this "01:04:415", and I still don't understand how to do it

Comment: No, don't use `Date` because that class is poory designed and long outdated. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Comment: Do your strings represent points in time, so approximately 3 and 4 minutes past the hour, or do they represent amounts of time (e.g., durations) that you need to subtract? The correct approach is different for the two cases.

Comment: @OleV.V. If I understood correctly, 1 case. This is about racing. Racer starts lap in startTime and finishes in finishTime. I need to calculate how long it takes hime and get the result in the same format

Comment: In that case I’d consider the answers by  Arvind Kumar Avinash and akuzminykh correct. Isn’t it a bit confusing to have the duration of the lap in the same format as the points in time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain `java.time.Duration` object by calculating the difference between the start time and finish time. Then, you can get the minute part, second part and millisecond part from the `Duration` object to get the required output.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String startTime = "02:58.917";
        String finishTime = "04:03.332";
        // Create a format by defaulting the hour to any value e.g. 0
        DateTimeFormatter format = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("mm:ss.SSS"))
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0).toFormatter();
        LocalTime firstTime = LocalTime.parse(startTime, format);
        LocalTime secondTime = LocalTime.parse(finishTime, format);
        Duration diff = Duration.between(firstTime, secondTime);
        String msms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%03d", diff.toMinutesPart(), diff.toSecondsPart(), diff.toMillisPart());
        System.out.println("The difference is " + msms);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
The difference is 01:04:415
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to do that using [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html):

```java
// create dtf for pattern where mm is minutes, ss is seconds, SSS is millis
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("mm:ss.SSS");

// we need to add a default value for hour so the parsing with LocalTime works
formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(formatter)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1)
        .toFormatter();

// parse the values
LocalTime t1 = LocalTime.parse("02:58.917", formatter);
LocalTime t2 = LocalTime.parse("04:03.332", formatter);

// get the millis between t1 and t2
System.out.println(t1.until(t2, ChronoUnit.MILLIS));

// another way
System.out.println(ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(t1, t2));

// you can get the result in the same format by adding the difference
// to a new LocalTime with all set to zero and using the formatter
LocalTime delta = LocalTime.of(1, 0, 0, 0)
        .plus(t1.until(t2, ChronoUnit.MILLIS), ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
System.out.println(delta.format(formatter));
```

Comment: But what I can do, if I need to get result in the same format, like this "01:04:415"?

Comment: @Ilya You can do that by creating a new `LocalTime` with all set to zero and adding the difference in millis to it. Then using the formatter gives you the desired `String`. Check out the edit and feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: Most of the answer is good. Using yet one more `LocalTime` for the duration between the first two is incorrect. Use a `Duration` as in the answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash. It’s also simpler.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for the consideration. I'll keep it as it is because it's an alternative. It's not incorrect, the result is the same. `Duration` may seem a bit more convenient though.

Comment: Can I ask one more question? I was wondering how it works with hours, and tried this code 

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss.SSS");
LocalTime t1 = LocalTime.parse("01:02:58.917", formatter);

But it failed. Can you tell what the problem?

Comment: @Ilya You have to open a seperate question for that.