# Regext to find text segments where text in not preceded by a number

Tags: java, regex

Using this text as an example: `foo 34abcd bar 7890xyz 123`.
Please help me find a regex to find all "orphan" numbers, that would be `123`;
and regex to find all "orphan" texts, that would be `foo` and `bar`.

To find all number followed immediately by a text is simple, I use a simple regex
`([0-9]+)([a-z]+)`. But how to find all non-conforming segments/words?

To find number not followed by a text, the "orphan" nuber, I tried to use regex negative look-ahead `([0-9]+)(?![a-z]+)`, but that return false positive like `3` from `34abcd`, because `3` is not followed by a letter. How can I make regex consider `34` and not a `3` and `4`?

To find texts not immediately predeced by a number, the "orphan" texts,
I tried regex with negative look-behind, `(?<![0-9]+)([a-z]+)`.
But it make false positive match on `34abcd` returning text `bcd`.
The look-behing seems to work only for exact texts, like (min|sec|year|years), but not for a any string of letters.

Background:
I'm trying to write a regex based parser for Java `Duration`, something more human friendly then the default parser in `Duration.parse`. Something what would parse "1h 30min 5sec" but also detect and report back any unparsable bits, like "foo bar 30min" shoudl complain about not recognizing "foo bar".

There is a question for that
[Parsing time strings like "1h 30min"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403851/parsing-time-strings-like-1h-30min)
but the suggested solutions are not satisfactory.

Comment: You need `(?<![0-9a-z])([a-z]+)`, include the letters into the character class inside the lookbehind.

Comment: Yep, @WiktorStribiżew you are absolutely right, it works for both look-aheads and look-behinds. Thank you! Feel free to add it as proper answer and I'm happy to approve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the letter pattern into the character class inside the lookbehind:

```
(?<![0-9a-z])([a-z]+)
```

Note that the capturing group around `[a-z]+` is superfluous, and should be removed.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G1PA5V/1).

Comment: I need the capturing because I wan to report back all "orphans".

Comment: Extra points for the interactive demo